# HTML parsing getElementByClass method

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I'm trying to parse html file and I'm at a point where I need to retrieve a table from the file.

Can I assume that `getElementsByClass` function returns the collection of elements in the order that it was met in the file? Same question for `getElementsByTag` and `getElementsById`.

```
Elements table_rows = tbody.getElementsByClass("table_row");
for(Element tr : table_rows){
    Elements table_datas = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, and it's depth first, pre-order traversal, I think. It's definitely not random, so you could experiment if you don't find a good source.

Comment: I haven't found the anwser to this question anywhere - neither on stackoverflow nor in documentation, hence my question.Regardless whether the question has been asked somewhere in the forum, I'm sure it will be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element.getElements* methods return elements in the order they appear in the document (using a depth-first preorder traversal) as easily verified from the source.  First, Elements.getElementsByClass, using an Evaluator that matches on class:

```
public Elements getElementsByClass(String className) {
    Validate.notEmpty(className);
    return Collector.collect(new Evaluator.Class(className), this);
}
```

The other getElements* methods are analogous (with different Evaluators, of course).  getElementById is similar except it only returns the first element from the collection (or null if the collection is empty).

Collector.collect just sets up a visitor which adds elements matching the Evaluator when first encountering the element (preorder):

```
public static Elements collect (Evaluator eval, Element root) {
    Elements elements = new Elements();
    new NodeTraversor(new Accumulator(root, elements, eval)).traverse(root);
    return elements;
}

private static class Accumulator implements NodeVisitor {
    /* uninteresting parts removed */
    public void head(Node node, int depth) {
        if (node instanceof Element) {
            Element el = (Element) node;
            if (eval.matches(root, el))
                elements.add(el);
        }
    }
}
```

NodeTraversor.traverse is explicitly documented as performing a depth-first traversal of its argument and all of its descendents, so I won't show the code here.

Comment: Does element id have to be unique in html file? If no, if I want to get 2nd element with the specified id in the html file, do I have to simply use getElementsById method 2 times?      And one more question: if I want to find a class="className" in my html file, and i know that its ancestors are named as follows: "father", "grandfather". Will it make much difference in speed of finding the className directly as opposed to writing: Element gfc = doc.getElementsByClass("grandfather").first(); fc = gfc.getElementsByClass("father").first(); className = fc.getElementsByClass("className")?

Comment: @user3142434: 1) id is supposed to be unique by the HTML standard, but if it isn't in your document, you'll need to call getElementById again from an element after the first id containing the second id to get the second one. 2) Calling getElementsByClass("className") makes a pass over the whole document; the grandfather-father-className approach makes a pass over the whole document _plus_ a pass over the grandfather element _plus_ a pass over the father element.  I wouldn't expect much practical difference, but the latter is slower.